# Install Composer on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I am trying to install composer with the command:

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And I am getting this error:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
Downloading...
Download failed: failed to open stream: Permission denied
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

I don't know why? Do you have an idea? I tryed to google it but nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your curl command is running as root (via sudo) but your php command is not.  Try moving your sudo between the pipe ("|") and 'php' (assuming you want your installer to run as root in the first place...).